# Different Time formats

Tags: php

I'm using this code

```
$today = date("j D M Y G:i:s T"); 
echo $today;
```

Output example : `22 Wed Feb 2012 15:22:24 EET` so what if i want to change EET (Estern europ time) to for example GMT ? and can anyone please give me reference where i can read more about different time formats to be used.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code..

```
 <?php
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Sofia');
   echo date_default_timezone_get();
   echo ' => '.date('T');
  ?>
```

Comment: Sofia is the capital and largest city of Bulgaria.

Comment: For details have a look onto this.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: okay got it "sofia" the capital of Bulgaria ~ never knew that way before !  date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

Answer (score 1):

You can use [date_default_timezone_set](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). Or for GMT you can just use [gmdate](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php).